# Compare master entry and select from child table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a Master table

```
      Type       category_1  category_2 category_3 category_4
    Type A          Y           N       Y           N
    Type B          Y           Y       Y           N
```

and a transaction table

```
    Trans-ID    Type    category
        1           A       1
        2           A       1
        3           B       4
        4           B       1
        5           A       2
        6           B       3
        7           A       3
```

I want to select all the entries from the transaction table whose categories are Y in master table.
The master table acts like a mask for the transaction table.

The output would be:

```
    Trans-ID    Type    category
        1           A       1
        2           A       1           
        4           B       1           
        6           B       3
        7           A       3
```

Could you please provide some hints on how to solve this with postgres?

Comment: This question needs a table definition where we can see data types and constraints. `\d tbl` in psql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `category_n` columns to be of type `boolean`.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   transaction t
LEFT   JOIN master m USING (type) -- must return single row
WHERE  CASE t.category
         WHEN 1 THEN m.category_1
         WHEN 2 THEN m.category_2
         WHEN 3 THEN m.category_3
         WHEN 4 THEN m.category_4
         ELSE FALSE -- should not occur
       END;
```

Parenthesis are optional here. Operator precedence works for us.

If referential integrity is enforced by a foreign key constraint and a `NOT NULL` constraint on `transaction.type`, you can use `[INNER] JOIN` instead of the `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` as well.

Comment: Any alternatives to the CASE statement since the master.category_x can grow to 30 i.e category_1, category_2... category_30.

Comment: @Sandeep: Did you see my request for data types and constraints?